# In iOS5 iPhone UITableView has extra grey footer?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

I have an iPhone app that uses several UITableViews.  For my main UITableView, when it is created it has a grey translucent cell that appears as the only cell.  After I load the data for my list, the grey cell still remains, but it is the bottom of the list.  In portrait mode this is not a big problem, because I have a toolbar at the bottom that covers it.  When rotated the grey cell acts as an overlay, and does not scroll off the bottom of the screen.  It stays stuck.

I the grey cell is not the footer.

Has anyone seen this behavior.  It is different in iOS5 simulators compared to iOS4.

Comment: If that's your only problem with iOS 5 you're doing pretty well:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8161486/581994

Comment: I've had other problems.  Mostly to do with retaining and voodoo memory management.  I've also found the solution.  My class had implemented heightForFooterInSection. If you do this you cannot remove the footer under any circumstances.  Removing the override fixed this problem.

Comment: If you've resolved the problem, please post it as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your UITableViewDelegate implements heightForFooterInSection, then ios5 puts a gray translucent footer on your list view.  You cannot hide this footer.  This behavior is new for ios5 it does not happen with ios4.  I removed the heightForFooterInSection and the problem resolved itself.

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to solve this issue..

None posted really worked for me..

```
CGRect tabFrame = self.table.frame;
tabFrame.size.height = tabFrame.size.height-25;
self.table.frame = tabFrame;
```